# WatiN referenced assembly error

Tags: c#, reference, console, assemblies, watin

I'm trying to get this basic Watin console application working however I'm running into the following error:

```
"Warning    1   The referenced assembly "WatiN.Core" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.  consoletest"
```

I have made sure to apply the  STAThread] attribute to the main method [as they recommend.](http://watin.org/documentation/sta-apartmentstate/for-console-or-winforms/)

Heres a screencap of the project a it stands: [Link](http://i42.tinypic.com/4gi0w7.jpg)

Additional notes: 
I have the latest version of watin installed (2.1) and
I managed to get a similar app running as a windows class file but need to be able to run this one directly and see the output so that's why I'm making a windows console app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Had the exact same problem.
Did this:
Right click on the project.
Go to Build
Changed the "Targe Framework" from .Net 4.0 target client to .Net 4.0 in the drop down
Then it started working.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your target framework from the client profile to the full .net 4 framework. Right click the project and go to properties and change it there. You then need to add a reference to System.Web.dll

Answer (score 0):

My apologies (it's entirely possible I'm about to learn something new!) but AFAIK WatiN is purely a web testing tool, you can't easily use it to test a console application.

I'd imagine that's why it's asking for a reference to System.Web.

If you want a library for testing a console app, Microsoft have one available http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163288.aspx

I hope that might help! :)

Comment: Ahh I see. Was just trying to achieve something similar to this video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqffNXMMCPM). Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Sure - I've edited my answer and included a link to the Microsoft UI automation framework *Test Run*. That might do what you need :)